# How to Authenticate using credentials in Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have a requirement to login to MVC web application using user credentials(username and password) in Azure Active Directory. Any idea how to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can login into the azure active directory by using the following method. For this you need to configure your account in active directly and give its values directly in your method and this will return you a token and from that token you have to initialize your class like this here Microsoft.Azure.TokenCloudCredentials("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxx", accessToken) and then you can perform any operation.

```
 public AuthenticationResult GetAccessToken()
{
    string hardcodedUsername = "activedirectoryusername";
    string hardcodedPassword = "activedirectorypassword";

    string tenant = "abc.onmicrosoft.com";
    string clientId = "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    string resourceHostUri = "https://management.core.windows.net/";
    string aadInstance = "https://login.windows.net/{0}";
    //string aadInstance = "https://login.windows.net/{0}/oauth2/authorize";

    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(String.Format(aadInstance, tenant));
    UserCredential userCredential = new UserPasswordCredential(hardcodedUsername, hardcodedPassword);
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;
    authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceHostUri, clientId, userCredential).Result;

    return authenticationResult;
}
```

Comment: i tried the same code before but i was getting "ID3242: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized." error. I have registered my APP in Active Directory .Took the ApplicationId as Client ID , Tenant as my tenant in AD, ResourceHostURI as my App ID URI and (tried https://management.core.windows.net/ both are not working) and credentials of user in AD. still i am receiving the error. Do i need to give any more permissions to the APP properties?

Comment: yes you need give to member role to that you active directory user and add under the user under same subscription that you have in your azure portal. and give full permission to that user according to your app.

Comment: what do you mean by full permission to that user ? and  the user with whom I am trying is an admin .  can you please post a screenshot , that would be helpful. thank you